# Symfony 3 HTTP Cache and Cross Origin Headers overwrite

Tags: angularjs, symfony, caching, cors, nelmiocorsbundle

I have a frontend AngularJS app that consumes backend API written in Symfony 3. I am using Symfony HTTP Cache to speed up some of my heavy responses.

I am in the testing phase, so my backend API adds 
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"*"` to all responses.

But, there is a problem with responses that are cached. In their header, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"*"` is overwritten with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"example.com"`, where `example.com` is the client address that requested resource just before it was cached.

So, if I open my frontend app on the address `www.example.com` instead of address `example.com` I see following error in the firebug

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://backend.com/tests/all. 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://example.com' 
that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using NelmioCorsBundle that adds CORS headers support to my Symfony3 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `forced_allow_origin_value: *` in your config:

```
 nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        …
        forced_allow_origin_value: *
```

Per [the configuration docs](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle#configuration):

> By default, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header value is
>   the `Origin` request header value (if it matches the rules you've
>   defined with `allow_origin`), so it should be fine for most of use
>   cases. If it's not, you can override this behavior  by setting the
>   exact value you want using `forced_allow_origin_value`.

So to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, the exact value you want is literally `*`.

Comment: Thank you very very much!
Adding `forced_allow_origin_value` in the config resolved my problem.

But, before that, I needet to update my NelmioCors to version 1.5, ant to put `*` in the qoutes.
`forced_allow_origin_value: '*'`

Comment: Thanks! It works for me, but with quotes:

`forced_allow_origin_value: '*'`

Comment: This solution basically is opening the gates for everyone. What we would need is being able to recalculate the CORS response headers when the response gets served via HTTP Cache, as that cache does also cache the headers.